# Android: How to set spinner selector to own image/icon?

Tags: android, coding-style, spinner

I have searching and testing to set my own image/icon in a Spinner but i get error.

I have alrady with styling set background image but then the spinner icon on the right side not shows anymore.

When i do like i find a example of like this:

```
<Spinner style="@style/Spinner" android:spinnerSelector="@drawable/myspinner_selector" />
```

And here is the myspinner_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_first="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown"
   />    
<item android:state_middle="true" 
   android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown"
   />       
<item android:state_last="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown"
   />   
<item android:state_single="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown"
   />
```

But it is in the first `XML`for spinner I get this error:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'spinnerSelector' in package 'android' `main.xml`
```

All example i can find on internet using the styling of spinner selector like this but i can not get it to work and can not find `spinnerSelector` in the reference guide on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) either.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't get the answer for changing the spinner image but you can do it..

1. Set the spinner height and width to 0dp
2. Create a button in the onClick() listener and call click action of the spinner like this

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           spin.performClick();
       }
   });
   ```
3. Change the button text to match the spinner text.

   ```
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
       button.setText(items[position]);
   }
   ```
4. Now you can change the image of the button easily!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
The only workaround I found is combining the selector icon to the background and then override the background only. Don't use the android:spinnerSelector attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I Think that xml style was changed

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/spinners.html