# How to change image of a spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

If we see a spinner it looks like a textview and with an image to the right of textview. In Motorola milestone that image is down arrow while in Samsung galaxy ace it is right arrow. I can set background image to a spinner using the following code. But I donot want to change the background image. I want to change that image. How to set that image of a spinner.

```
Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnContactTypes1);
sp1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to [change the spinner selector](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57)

This is done with:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
 android:spinnerSelector="@drawable/myspinner_selector">
```

and in `myspinner_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_first="true"
      android:state_dropdown_showing="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_down"/>  
<!-- other states ... -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi rds, The link tells to change the selector. Hence to change the whole background. Is there any way which will not affect to the background but only change the image?

Comment: What do you mean, you don't want to change the background behind the selector?

Comment: i want the background will be as it is. Only the image to change. in selector i have to put image with white background and at the right of this only image with different color

Comment: i dint find android:spinnerSelector for selector in android 2.1

Comment: You are right, it seems this attribute has disappeared. Try `listSelector` or use the hack given in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535109/android-how-to-set-spinner-selector-to-own-image-icon

Comment: `android:spinnerSelector`??  That doesn't even compile.