# How can I have this overlayed DropDown or Spinner structure in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-custom-view

I need to know how I can have this kind of spinner structure, as seen in image [Drop Down Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykDmn.png). When you click on this spinner, the drop down opens up.

Comment: Check this: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/android-spinnersdropdownlist-tutorial.html#.VaTQm7f6mjw

Comment: Kindly explain ... Stack does not accept link answers

Comment: @serv serv1: He didn't answer with a link, he commented on your post :-)

Comment: You need to use style.xml as well as the solution is given on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755878/how-can-i-fix-the-spinner-style-for-android-4-x-placed-on-top-of-the-toolbar

Comment: I was thinking of inflating a new layout on click of spinner

Comment: On click of Spinner a new Layout gets inflated at exact that position and then on back take out the inflated layout