# How can I replace the icon arrow of spinner in Android with an image?

Tags: android

I would like to change the default spinner icon arrow in Android with a custom image.

I made my custom spinner (based on this answer: [How to customize a Spinner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android#answer-17213328), just changing the custom values) and it works well but I am not able to change the arrow of the spinner neither on styles or programatically.

I saw this question: [How to change image of a spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762362/how-to-change-image-of-a-spinner) but as I do not have a `Spinner` tag it does not allow me to add the attribute `android:spinnerSelector`.

How can I replace the default arrow icon with an image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short example:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        R.layout.custom_spinner,
        ITEMS
);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then create a custom xml (named:custom_spinner.xml) for spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="yourTextsize"
    android:drawablePadding="paddingValueYouWant"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" <!--your custom icon-->
    />
```

For more customization spinner, follow this artircle: [How to set font custom font to Spinner text programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483495/how-to-set-font-custom-font-to-spinner-text-programmatically/25510848#25510848)

Comment: Ok I could add the custom dropdown arrow using `android:drawableRight` but now it shows both the default icon arrow and the new image icon that I have added. How can I only show the second one?

Comment: you can give a background `android:background="@drawable/bg"` or `android:background="@null"`for spinner and it should be invisible :)

Comment: When you put `@drawable/bg` do you mean to use a custom background? I tried with `android:background="@null"` but it does not change anything.

Comment: oh sorry, i have never use CheckedTextview for spinner :(

Comment: I am sorry, I had a big confusion in my head and I forgot that I was using the TextView and CheckedTextview to set the adapter to the spinner so finally I was using a Spinner :'). Now it works well using `android:background="@null"`. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly change it in style,

```
<style name="CustomSpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_arrow</item>
</style>
```

Just use the drawable icon whichever you want and then set the theme in the spinner

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/CustomSpinnerTheme"/>
```