# Android error when adding a spinnerSelector, no resource identifier found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-spinner

I want to change the color of the list selector on a spinner item to something other than the ugly, orange default.  From what I read, the way to do this is to set the `android:spinnerSelector` property.  However, in Eclipse, I get this error when I try to set the `android:spinnerSelector` property

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'spinnerSelector' in package 
>    'android'

Here is my xml file with the spinner in it;

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkgray" >
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/timespinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerSelector="@drawable/my_selector"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:prompt="@string/timeprompt" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535109/android-how-to-set-spinner-selector-to-own-image-icon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `android:spinnerSelector` attribute is no longer part of the API.
This post may have a workaround: [Android: How to set spinner selector to own image/icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535109/android-how-to-set-spinner-selector-to-own-image-icon)